# UNKNOWN COMMAND

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am unable to use FETCH in ORACLE SQL , it is giving the error UNKNOWN COMMAND while I am trying to use FETCH or LIMIT , I cannot find any suitable solution for this issue.

Comment: Do you know how difficult it is to debug code you can't see? The way you put it, I presume that you're on Oracle database version which doesn't support clause you're trying to use. For example, that might be 11g. Is it? If not, then: which database version do you use and which query did you run?

Comment: The `FETCH ... ROWS ONLY` syntax is only available from Oracle 12 and `LIMIT` is not supported syntax in Oracle (but is in MySQL). Use the syntax in the linked duplicate.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0